# Meteor: How to dynamically update source of aldeed tabular

Tags: meteor, datatables

I am using meteor aldeed tabular package and was able to successfully get data into it. I can use server side selector to restrict it to what I want but I need the contents to change depending on what I click elsewhere on the client side. Can client pass the value to server, say parent id, and change from server side what children are shown in tabular?

Comment: you can pass parameters to your publications and change those parameters on the client every time you click. i am guessing aldeed tabular uses publications also to grab the data.

Comment: aldeed tubular uses pub sub but isn't it hidden to us? Should i not restrict what is sent to the client from server in the first place?

Comment: so can you have custom publications? [look at this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular#using-a-custom-publish-function). See if that helps

Comment: Thanks! i used it but it refuses to accept any changes to currentClickedId in `return items.find({ type: "File", parent: currentClickedId });` and update on client accordingly. Is it because even compositePublish is static in what it accepts as sources and it is better to use my own publish function for `pub:` option?